# Get distinct name first explode by brackets in string than sort in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My table before query

[image]

My query

```
<?php $sql="SELECT distinct(SUBSTRING(name,1,instr(name,'(')-1)), pid,sort_order from extra GROUP BY (SUBSTRING(name,1,instr(name,'(')-1)) ORDER BY sort_order ASC LIMIT 0,15"; ?>
```

Given output
[image]

My requirement
[image]

Comment: when you use group by you need to execute aggrecate funtion on the two field  pid,sort_order  what do you need exactly is the number of name that start with the same three lettres ?

Comment: I need unique string name sort by sort_order ASC and then show result.

Comment: edit your question and explain why pid = 3 and 7  because 7 is the max value for name start with yyy but 3 is not the max try to be more clear

Comment: Please look at the column 'name' start with **xxx**. There are 4 products when i run my query it gives me first product, but i required product **xxx** which sort_order will be 2 means Order by ASC.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want the products  with min sort_order that starts with the same 3 lettres

```
 SELECT 
     ext.*
  FROM extra ext
  INNER JOIN (
  -- this query return the sub_name with the min_order for that sub_name
  SELECT 
        distinct(SUBSTRING(name,1,instr(name,'(')-1)) as 'sub_name',
        min(sort_order)
  from extra
  group by sub_name
  ) min_extra on SUBSTRING(extname,1,instr(ext.name,'(')-1) = min_extra.sub_name
 ORDER BY ext.sort_order ASC LIMIT 0,15";
```

Comment: i just assumed what you want but you can edit the query to get what you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution using this query.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(pp.name,1,instr(pp.name,'(')-1),(select e.pid from extra as e where SUBSTRING(e.name,1,instr(pp.name,'(')-1)=SUBSTRING(pp.name,1,instr(pp.name,'(')-1) order by e.sort_order asc limit 1) as pid from extra as pp group by SUBSTRING(name,1,instr(name,'(')-1) order by pp.sort_order asc
```